# I am having 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'allIds' of undefined(…)' error on my declared constant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am following a redux tutorial series [here](https://github.com/tayiorbeii/egghead.io_idiomatic_redux_course_notes/blob/master/11-Normalizing_the_State_Shape.md), I don't know why I am having this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'allIds' of undefined(…)**. 
This is the code

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todo from './todo';

const byId = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: todo(state[action.id], action),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const allIds = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [...state, action.id];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const todos = combineReducers({
  byId,
  allIds,
});

export default todos;

const getAllTodos = (state) =>
  state.allIds.map(id => state.byId[id]); // <- THE ERROR IS HERE

export const getVisibleTodos = (state, filter) => {
  const allTodos = getAllTodos(state);
  switch (filter) {
    case 'all':
      return allTodos;
    case 'completed':
      return allTodos.filter(t => t.completed);
    case 'active':
      return allTodos.filter(t => !t.completed);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown filter: ${filter}.`);
  }
};
```

I thought the error was because I didn't configure the preset for spread operator, but after installing and configured Stage 2 preset, I still have the error on allIds. Why do I have this error in allIds?

Comment: Keep the whole code here, not only this `todos.js` file

Comment: The error isn't in the code you included. For some reason the state isn't passed into `getVisibleTodos` (state is undefined). You havn't included the code where you call this function, so in order to help you further, you need to show the code where you call this function.